# getImageData() returns wrong data when panning/zooming canvas (Physical mobile device issue only)

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage, getimagedata, panzoom

### Context:

I'm using Andrei Kashcha's (anvaka) panzoom library: https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom to provide detailed color picking functionalities:

[image]

I've created a 1' movie to illustrate the use case: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tv9rs18vvpv95d/tfs_cp.mov?dl=0

### Issue:

**- Part I [ Resolved, see below for Part II which remains unresolved ]**

// 14-12-2020: Initial post

This all works fine on both Chrome/Safari on Desktop, but when switching to Mobile, I'm receiving the following error on touchend (_listener2):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at cp_vfinal:1229
    at useCanvas (cp_vfinal:761)
    at HTMLImageElement._listener2 (cp_vfinal:1221)
```

More specifically, the following part of the code which I've shared below:

```
var p = inst.canvas.getContext('2d')
                .getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
```

My assumption is that this error will also manifest on touchmove (_listener4), but I cannot test this properly with Chrome's built-in Mobile device-mode. I also have no access to XCode, which makes it also difficult to test in Safari.

// 29/12: Update

Meanwhile I figured out that following piece of code was causing the ReferenceError:

```
// chrome
if(e.offsetX) {
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY; 
}
// firefox
else if(e.layerX) {
    x = e.layerX;
    y = e.layerY;
}
```

Replacing this by the following, resolved my issue.

```
x = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - e.changedTouches[0].target.offsetLeft
y = e.changedTouches[0].clientY - e.changedTouches[0].target.offsetTop;
```

**- Part II [ Unresolved ]**

// 14-12-2020: Initial post

When zooming/panning on Mobile and subsequently selecting a color on Mobile, it seems that the color selection made is based on a canvas that is not yet zoomed/panned.

I've tried quite some things already, but I simply cannot figure it out. Although other's have attempted the same:

- [Implementing zoom on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175419/implementing-zoom-on-canvas)
- [Zooming canvas on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632859/zooming-canvas-on-mobile)
- [Horrible Canvas GetImageData() / PutImageData() performance on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453712/horrible-canvas-getimagedata-putimagedata-performance-on-mobile)
- [Canvas getImageData returning incorrect data on certain mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680481/canvas-getimagedata-returning-incorrect-data-on-certain-mobile-devices)

I couldn't use that input to resolve my issue either.

// 29-12-2020: Update

As of today, I still wasn't able to resolve the second part of the issue.

When comparing

```
console.log(inst.canvas);
console.log(inst.canvas.getContext('2d'))
```

for both mobile and desktop I don't see any difference, so it's really strange that on mobile I cannot retrieve the correct data through getImageData(). How can I ensure that getImageData() is actually checking for the zoomed/scaled/panned image (canvas) and not for the unzoomed/unscaled/unpanned image (canvas)? That would already help me debug further.

// 05-04-2021: Update

I still haven't figured out what causes the issue. Three key questions remain:

- Q1: Am I using drawImage() correctly?
- Q2: Am I using getImageData() correctly?
- Q3: Regardless of Q1/Q2, why is it working on Desktop
  then?

// 15-05-2021: Update

I still haven't figured out what causes the issue. The same key questions remain, but I've made some progress in terms of investigations:

- Q1: Am I using drawImage() correctly?

I've now tried to use void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight); instead of void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight); as this seemed more logical after reading the documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage Unfortunately this didn't change much. I've updated below visualization to reflect my adjustments.

- Q2: Am I using getImageData() correctly?

I have no idea what could be wrong here.

- Q3: Regardless of Q1/Q2, why is it working on Desktop
  then?

I've also tested my implementation in a smartphone simulator: https://www.webmobilefirst.com/en/ Works like a charm. Hence it's really the physical device that is causing the issues.

**Visualization:**

The testimage with intrinsic dimensions of 2075x3112 is loaded into a canvas with width = 375 and height = 562 - this is the situation on the left. The situation on the right depicts what happens after panning/zooming.

[image]

### Snippets:

- drawImage(): called when panning/zooming

```
function useCanvas(el, image, callback){
    console.log("useCanvas")
    console.log(image);
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage
    //console.log(el.width);
    //console.log(el.height);
    if(!checkCanvasSize(el, image)){
        console.log("checkCanvasSize")
        el.width = image.width; // img width
        el.height = image.height; // img height

        console.log(el.width);
        console.log(el.height);
        
        // draw image in canvas tag - void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
        el.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        console.log(el)
        console.log(el.getContext('2d'))
    } else {
        console.log("else ...")
        console.log(image.style.transform)
        //if no transformation - do nothing
        //if transformation - do "something"
        if(image.style.transform !== "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)"){
            //- draw transformed image onto canvas
            el.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        }
    }
    return callback();
}
```

- getImageData()

```
_listener2 = function(e) { //touchend

        //console.log(e.srcElement)
        tlength = e.touches.length;
        cpsig1 = cpsig1 + tlength.toString();
        if(tlength === 0){

            if( (tf.x < -1E-9 || tf.x > 1E-9) || (tf.y < -1E-9 || tf.y > 1E-9) || tf.scale > 1){ //pan or zoom is true
                //activate CP again
                activateCP = true;
                //wait for the next user action to do something (e.g. click/tap)
                if(cpsig1.slice(cpsig1.length - 2) === "00"){
                    registerC = true;
                } else {
                    registerC = false;
                }
            } else { 
                //perform a check whether we came from a 'transformed' situation or not, in case yes, don't set the color.
                if(transform === true){ //we came from a 'transformed' situation
                    registerC = false; //we wait for a user action
                    transform = false;
                    //tmpvar = true;
                } else { //register the underlying color that was touched before going to TE=0 and move to next color (registerC should be true here)
                    //extra handle
                    if(cpsig1.slice(cpsig1.length - 2) === "20"){
                        registerC = false;
                    } else {
                        registerC = true;
                    }
                    
                }
            }

            
        }

        // chrome
        if(e.offsetX) {
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY; 
        }
        // firefox
        else if(e.layerX) {
            x = e.layerX;
            y = e.layerY;
        }
        useCanvas(inst.canvas, inst.img, function(){
            // get image data
            //console.log("Debug:")
            //console.log(inst.img);
            //console.log(inst.canvas);
            //console.log(inst.canvas.getContext('2d'))
            //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas
            var p = inst.canvas.getContext('2d')
                .getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                        
            // show info
            inst.result_hex = rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
            inst.result_rgb_string = 'rgb('+p[0]+','+ p[1]+','+ p[2]+')';
            
            // set value
            console.log("skinSelection: ", skinSelection)
            if(skinSelection === false && tlength === 0 && registerC === true){
                document.getElementById("preview_skin").style.backgroundColor = rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
                document.getElementById("preview_skin").style.backgroundSize = "42.5px 42.5px"
                document.getElementById("preview_skin").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/3e929c_000c0389ad654985be5d7983694c7695~mv2.png')";
                document.getElementById("preview_skin").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
                document.getElementById("preview_skin").style.backgroundPosition = "center 50%"
                skinSelection = true;
                document.getElementById('preview_skin').style.border = "5px solid #fff";
            } else {
                if(hairSelection === false && tlength === 0 && registerC === true){
                    document.getElementById("preview_hair").style.backgroundColor = rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
                    document.getElementById("preview_hair").style.backgroundSize = "42.5px 42.5px"
                    document.getElementById("preview_hair").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/3e929c_cad76816bc4441b6bfe34f5008b2741d~mv2.png')";
                    document.getElementById("preview_hair").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
                    document.getElementById("preview_hair").style.backgroundPosition = "center 50%"
                    hairSelection = true;
                    document.getElementById('preview_hair').style.border = "5px solid #fff"
                } else {
                    if(eyeSelection === false && tlength === 0 && registerC === true){
                        document.getElementById("preview_eye").style.backgroundColor = rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
                        document.getElementById("preview_eye").style.backgroundSize = "42.5px 42.5px"
                        document.getElementById("preview_eye").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/3e929c_f628dfa5fe0a412da6f06954a8657458~mv2.png')";
                        document.getElementById("preview_eye").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
                        document.getElementById("preview_eye").style.backgroundPosition = "center 50%"
                        eyeSelection = true;
                        document.getElementById('preview_eye').style.border = "5px solid #fff"
                    }
                }

            }
            console.log("R: " + p[0] + " - G: " + p[1] + " - B: " + p[2]);
        });
    }
```

### 'MWE':

As it is difficult to create a MWE for this, I will share the full working example which can be found here: https://yvervoort.github.io/cp-acc_web_v0.2.html The Javascript is available under the 'sources' tab of your Developer Tools.

### Changelog:

- 14-12-2020: Initial question
- 29-12-2020: Updated question - Part I resolved | Part II remains unresolved
- 29-12-2020: Updated title to better reflect what remains to be resolved
- 05-04-2021: Updated explanation (included a visualization of the issue) and added new key questions I believe are related to the issue of Part II which remains unresolved
- 15-05-2021: Updated the progress I made, which is limited. I do know now that the implementation also works fine on a smartphone emulator and hence only seems to cause issues on the actual physical device.